# Smooth scroll to top pagination from Ajax extension

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery

How can I implement smooth scroll to top in a ajax extension that does pagination. The extension has the code following

```
if (block && amshopby_scroll_to_products) {
    $$('body')[0].scrollTo();
}
```

and I have following code in my theme phtml which does smooth scroll to top functionality. Is it possible to call this functionality from the extension js file mentioned above.If not what is the the solution to implement?

```
    var windowScroll_t;
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        clearTimeout(windowScroll_t);
        windowScroll_t = setTimeout(function() {

            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100)
            {
                $('#scroll-to-top').fadeIn();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#scroll-to-top').fadeOut();
            }

        }, 500);

    });

    $('#scroll-to-top').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600, "easeOutCubic");
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably use Amasty module, I had the same problem. There is hidden option in amshopby-ajax.js just change false to true. and ajax filtering will scroll to top

```
var amshopby_toolbar_selector = 'div.toolbar';
var amshopby_scroll_to_products = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is not related to magento at all but, I love to answer this question,

use [this](https://markgoodyear.com/2013/01/scrollup-jquery-plugin/) Jquery plugin , and integrate in product view page. see its demo and how to implement section you will easily integrate this beautiful plugin.

https://markgoodyear.com/2013/01/scrollup-jquery-plugin/